# Memory access overlapping a region

Tags: arm

In ARM architecture, what would happen if a memory access is inside and outside a region of a MPU.

Let say I want a 32bit memory access using LDR to an unaligned location: 0x000a03e.

If I have a MPU region starting at 0xa000 and ending at 0xa003f.
The access to 0x000a03e will have 0x000a03e and 0x000a03f bytes in the region and 0x000a040-0x000a041 outside the region (Hitting the background region).

Will the memory controller issue 2 reads: One 16bit read starting from 0x000a03e and one other starting from 0x000a040 ?

If one of them is invalid (data abort,...), will the overall LDR fail ?

Comment: which core and how have you configured it with respect to unaligned accesses, etc.?

Comment: If this is a cortex-m then AHB documentation, but should be similar to amba/axi.

Comment: reads are at bus width and then the byte lanes extracted at the core.  if your bus is 16 bits wide (what core is this??) then that might happen but it is more like a 32 or 64 bit bus is there.  and yes it is likely it is split into two separate bus transactions.

Comment: what happened when you tried it?  to make this an SO question you need to post code, expected and actual results.